# TPL on PCL of mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I see i can't use TPL in the CORE projects.

Is the PCL doesn't support System.Threading.Tasks?
(i checked on profile104 and there is no System.Threading.Tasks namespace,
but on profile 131 there is...)

So, is there a way to use mvvmcross with TPL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to use TPL with portable class libraries.

1. You can use a profile like 104 and extend it with the BCL AsyncBridge support classes. For more on this see http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-004 and the resources. Several people have done this - but I don't know of anyone who's fully documented the process.
2. You can use a profile like 78 which supports TPL and await/async natively - but this doesn't support WP7.x

This should be much easier when the official Xamarin PCL support is available

Comment: **There is a problem with Profile 78 with android:**  

  
Error 1 Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. **Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?**
File name: 'System.Runtime.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: please ask a new good question about how to get it running in android - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - don't try to debug in comments - it's too hard here

Comment: I put my core lib with Profile 78, but when I want to use this lib in Xamarin.ios project I have an error about System.Object and ask to add reference to System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0.  How did you do zahi ?  Thanks