# TPL on PCL for MvvmCross for PCL Profile 78

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Trying to use `PCL` for `mvvmcross` with TPL by Profile 78
(regarding question [TPL on PCL of mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914738/tpl-on-pcl-of-mvvmcross))

On `iOS` project it's working, but NOT for `android`.
here the Error:

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'System.Runtime.dll' at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolve
```

So,
does anyone know how to use Profile 78 with android
(or other profile to work with that includes TPL) ?

Comment: I've had the most success with Profile78 and the Alpha channels of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS (Alphas as of today, they should soon graduate to Beta).

Answer (score 0):

We're using Profile111 and Profile259 (on different projects) with MvvmCross.

[image: Configured Profile111 in Xamarin Studio]