# Xamarin shim assemblies and PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, assemblies, portable-class-library

I want to be able to convert some existing code which uses standard.csproj, droid.csproj and ios.csproj so that they are all based on PCL thus simplifying the solution.

I have read and looked at the shim solution suggested here:

http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html

But:

1: I am unsure how to actually use the shim assemblies - do I reference these instead of the GAC versions?

2: There is a lot of mention that iOS isn't working yet. Is this the case?

w://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official support for PCLs from Xamarin is due in Alpha any day now - expect it before the end of June 2013.

Until then, you can see how to use PCLs by including the shim assemblies from MvvmCross - take a look at:

- the `PortableSupport` shims source - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/PortableSupport
- the Nuget 2.5 `PortableSupport` package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.PortableSupport/
- the 25 videos on http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/ all of which use PCLs
- the accompanying source code for those videos - the .csproj files will show you how the shims are used - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross
- lots of other PCL based x-plat samples on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/

For additional shims, watch questions like [TPL on PCL for MvvmCross for PCL Profile 78](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936253/tpl-on-pcl-for-mvvmcross-for-pcl-profile-78) (I know people have got this working - just waiting for them to answer the question...)

When Xamarin official PCL support ships then I anticipate that they will ship official shims and we can retire the MvvmCross ones. However, no-one at Xamarin has given me any answer about this - for latest on this, maybe see status of https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8035

Comment: So for each PCL I need to add the PortableSupport nugets? Or do I just add them to the droid and ios app projects?

Comment: In the 2 minutes since I posted my answer, you can't possibly have read all those links let alone watched any of the videos or examined any of the files on github. Maybe you should try that?

Comment: I had already looked at all the source for the mvvm samples and can't find how they are linked. I don't really want to watch 25 videos this am unless I rrrrrreally have to ;)

Comment: And I appreciate that sounds like I'm being lazy but I had already also watched a few of the videos last night. I can't see anywhere so far that shows using the shim assemblies :)

Comment: "the .csproj files will show you how the shims are used". TBH, it does sound like you are being lazy... and it also sounds like you are trying to solve a problem you haven't hit yet. Why not try to build your PCL solution - it will soon become apparent when/where you need shims. Over and out from me on this one - I've tried to help, but not sure I've succeeded - sorry.

Comment: You definitely have helped. I have converted all of the projects over to use PCL and can see all the errors - it's just there isn't a lot out there about shim libraries. Thank you - I wasn't being lazy, just felt a bit like feeling my way through the dark.

Comment: Once I've wrapped my head around this I will blog in laymans terms to help get the word out about it as I think this is really important work. I'm suprised Xamarin haven't taken the lead with this and to be air - hats off to you for your efforts.

Comment: "I have converted all of the projects over to use PCL and can see all the errors" > In which case why are you asking questions about shim assemblies? I would guess your problem is "all the errors" whatever they are? I can't tell from here, but maybe you're trying to look for a hammer, but you need a screwdriver? People might be able to help if they know what the errors are... Really over-and-out this time - I won't return to this question...

Comment: What's with the attitude!??! THE ERRORS ARE OBVIOUSLY MISSING REFERENCES TO NAMESPACES WHICH ARE FIXED BY SHIM ASSEMBLIES - THAT WAS THE PROBLEM YOU WERE TRYING TO FIX NO?!!? you need to get a grip dude - you're attitude sucks.

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles on this: you can't fix 'missing namespaces' using this type of shim assembly and SHOUTING at people doesn't help either. To fix missing namespaces you need to extend portable class libraries - Daniel Plaisted provided some excellent advice on this - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx

Comment: I'm actually trying to resolve IPAdress etc which this would fix if it worked :/