# Async/Await in portable class library targeting Windows Store, iOS and Droid

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Developping an MvvmCross application targeting Android and iOS (Xamarin/Mono) and Windows Store (because it's so easy/fast to debug compared to iOS/Android).

The Core of the app is PCL based.

Is it possible to use Async/Await in the Core library?

Xamarin mono supports Async/Await, and Windows Store supports it. 
However, when selecting only Net4.5, Windows Store, Mono Android and MonoTouch as the PCL targets, SL4 and WP7.5 get automatically selected and Async/Await is not availlable anymore.

Comment: Last I heard, Xamarin support for both PCL and `async` are in the Beta stage and don't work well together. However, I'm hoping that Xamarin/Microsoft will announce something like this at Microsoft's Build conference (starting tomorrow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest I have is: [TPL on PCL of mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914738/tpl-on-pcl-of-mvvmcross/16915025#16915025)

But PCL support from Xamarin has officially launched in the last week - so the latest I have is be out of date. Miguel has promised a blog post on the current status when he returns from Build.

Also, I have seen user comments like "I'm using asyncbridge and profile47 with heavily usage of async inside PCL. Works perfect on iOs and Android, with MvvmCross events it looks like a magic" from http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/18872/#Comment_18872 - would love to see this more fully blogged, explained, documented by those who have it working.