# How to get Aysnc/Await support on MVVMCross with Profile 104?

Tags: asynchronous, profile, mvvmcross, async-await, printer-control-language

I use VS2012 and everything is from stable channel only. Also MVVMCross is up to date.
I thought Xamarin already released official support for async/await in PCL?

But I still can't add System.Threading.Tasks in the Core PCL project.

I read that somewhere we can change it Profile78 to make it work naively. 
But latest mvvmcross still using profile104, there must be a reason for that?

My question is how can I get async/await working naively or non-natively on profile 104?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought Xamarin already released official support for async/await in PCL?

Xamarin have told me that they have not officially announced any PCL support (although their release notes show they have shipped bits).

MvvmCross ships using Profile104 because MvvmCross supports WP7 - but that doesn't mean your apps need to use Profile104 - you can use the profile you want to use (as long as it can consume 104)

Until Xamarin officially release their PCL support and more information about it, then I think the answer to this question remains at [TPL on PCL of mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914738/tpl-on-pcl-of-mvvmcross/16915025#16915025) and [Async/Await in portable class library targeting Windows Store, iOS and Droid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302766/async-await-in-portable-class-library-targeting-windows-store-ios-and-droid)